# PDF files, not being crawled?

Tags: 2010, search, search-results

I have one site collection with shared documents. I uploaded one PDF file with the name listitem.pdf. I followed [this procedure to add the PDF IFilter](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2293357). I also added in file types, the pdf extension. Now I can see the PDF icon. I performed a full crawl. However, I can't see yet the PDF option in Result Type in the refinement panel. I also edited the XML filter category definition for this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <FilterCategories>   <Category  Title="Result Type"    Description="The file extension of the item"    Type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.ManagedPropertyFilterGenerator" MetadataThreshold="1"    NumberOfFiltersToDisplay="0"    MaxNumberOfFilters="0"    SortBy="Frequency"    SortDirection="Descending"    SortByForMoreFilters="Name"    SortDirectionForMoreFilters="Ascending"     ShowMoreLink="True"    MappedProperty="FileExtension"    MoreLinkText="show more"    LessLinkText="show fewer">
    <CustomFilters MappingType="ValueMapping" DataType="String" ValueReference="Absolute" ShowAllInMore="False">
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="Adobe PDF">
        <OriginalValue>pdf</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="Email">
        <OriginalValue>eml</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>msg</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>exch</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="Excel">
        <OriginalValue>odc</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>ods</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>xls</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>xlsb</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>xlsm</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>xlsx</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="Image">
        <OriginalValue>tif</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>tiff</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="Lotus Notes">
        <OriginalValue>nsf</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="OneNote">
        <OriginalValue>one</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="PowerPoint">
        <OriginalValue>odp</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>ppt</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>pptm</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>pptx</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="Publisher">
        <OriginalValue>pub</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="Text">
        <OriginalValue>odt</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>txt</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>url</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>csv</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="Visio">
        <OriginalValue>vdw</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>vdx</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>vsd</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>vss</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>vst</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>vsx</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>vtx</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="Webpage">
        <OriginalValue>ascx</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>asp</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>aspx</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>htm</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>html</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>jhtml</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>js</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>mht</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>mhtml</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>mspx</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>php</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue></OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="XML">
        <OriginalValue>xml</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="Word">
        <OriginalValue>doc</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>docm</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>docx</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>dot</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>nws</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="Zip">
        <OriginalValue>zip</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
    </CustomFilters>   </Category>   <Category    Title="Site"    Description="Which site this document is from"    Type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.ManagedPropertyFilterGenerator" MetadataThreshold="5"    NumberOfFiltersToDisplay="4"    MaxNumberOfFilters="20"    SortBy="Frequency"    SortByForMoreFilters="Name"    SortDirection="Descending"    SortDirectionForMoreFilters="Ascending"    ShowMoreLink="True"    MappedProperty="SiteName"    MoreLinkText="show more"    LessLinkText="show fewer" />   <Category    Title="Author"    Description="Use this filter to restrict results authored by a specific author"    Type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.ManagedPropertyFilterGenerator" MetadataThreshold="5"    NumberOfFiltersToDisplay="4"    MaxNumberOfFilters="20"    SortBy="Frequency"    SortByForMoreFilters="Name"    SortDirection="Descending"    SortDirectionForMoreFilters="Ascending"    ShowMoreLink="True"    MappedProperty="Author"    MoreLinkText="show more"    LessLinkText="show fewer"    />   <Category    Title="Modified Date"   Description="When the item was last updated"    Type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.ManagedPropertyFilterGenerator" MetadataThreshold="5"    NumberOfFiltersToDisplay="6"    MaxNumberOfFilters="0"    SortBy="Custom"    ShowMoreLink="True"    MappedProperty="Write"    MoreLinkText="show more"    LessLinkText="show fewer" >
    <CustomFilters MappingType="RangeMapping" DataType="Date" ValueReference="Relative" ShowAllInMore="False">
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="Past 24 Hours">
        <OriginalValue>-1..</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="Past Week">
        <OriginalValue>-7..</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="Past Month">
        <OriginalValue>-30..</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="Past Six Months">
        <OriginalValue>-183..</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="Past Year">
        <OriginalValue>-365..</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="Earlier">
        <OriginalValue>..-365</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
    </CustomFilters>   </Category>   <Category    Title="Managed Metadata Columns"    Description="Managed metadata of the documents"   Type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.TaxonomyFilterGenerator" MetadataThreshold="3"    NumberOfFiltersToDisplay="3"    MaxNumberOfFilters="20"    ShowMoreLink="True"    MappedProperty="ows_MetadataFacetInfo"    MoreLinkText="show more"    LessLinkText="show fewer" />   <Category    Title="Tags"    Description="All managed metadata of the documents and social tags"    Type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.TaxonomyFilterGenerator" MetadataThreshold="3"    NumberOfFiltersToDisplay="3"    MaxNumberOfFilters="20"    ShowMoreLink="True"    MappedProperty="ows_MetadataFacetInfo,popularsocialtags"    MoreLinkText="show more"    LessLinkText="show fewer" />   <Category Title="Content Type" Description="The content type of the item" Type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.ManagedPropertyFilterGenerator" MetadataThreshold="0" NumberOfFiltersToDisplay="10" MaxNumberOfFilters="0" SortBy="Frequency" SortDirection="Descending" SortByForMoreFilters="Name" SortDirectionForMoreFilters="Ascending" ShowMoreLink="True" MappedProperty="ContentTypeRefinement" MoreLinkText="show more" LessLinkText="show fewer">    <CustomFilters MappingType="ValueMapping" DataType="String" ShowAllInMore="False" ValueReference="Absolute">        <CustomFilter CustomValue="Document Mirage Teams">          <OriginalValue>Mirage Teams Document</OriginalValue>        </CustomFilter>     </CustomFilters>   </Category>   </FilterCategories>
```

No Idea what else to do

Comment: Estaban - I removed the numbered list from your introduction and that seemed to enable the code formatting to work properly.

Comment: is there anyway to know if the PDF was indexed or not?

Comment: Check your crawl log in Search Administration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors I noticed in my procedure for other users to read:

- Restarting IIS does not restart search services.
- I was doing an incremental crawl instead of full crawl.
- I found this site in which they do something additional in the registry
  http://nickgrattan.wordpress.com/2010/06/14/adobe-pdf-ifilter-indexing-with-sharepoint%C2%A02010/

After following all of these, it works perfect.

Comment: If you hadn't added the registry entry for the filter extension that was likely the culprit. The "official" Microsoft support document explicitly calls out that step (just in case you want the doc for future reference): http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2293357. It also calls out that a full crawl must be run once that configuration is complete.

Answer (score 0):

There is a parameter called "MetadataThreshold" that I think defaults to 5. That number is the number of rows that must appear in the search results for the refiner to show up.

If the number of search results is below that threshold the refiner won't show.

Comment: MetadataThreshold="1"

Comment: Are you searching for a term that returns a decent amount of items, and items that are mixed (i.e. powerpoint documents, word documents, and pdfs?). If you only get one type of document returned, you won't see a refiner either.

Comment: I named all my word files,excel, txt, and pdf with the same name: listitem.  in the refinement panel its showing, excel, webpage, text, and word, but its not showing pdf.